# What is use of absolute Path on Json file of a Smart Contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-design, tokens

What is the use of `absolutePath` on JSON artifact of a Smart Contract?
Does this mean we need the .sol file on the same server where web3.js apis are running?

```
{
    "absolutePath": "/home/hashcode01/HashCode/Github Project/AegisCoinGitHub/contracts/BusinessAcc.sol",
    "file": "./BusinessAcc.sol",
    "id": 9,
    "nodeType": "ImportDirective",
    "scope": 720,
    "sourceUnit": 793,
    "src": "367:27:0",
    "symbolAliases": [],
    "unitAlias": ""
},
```

Comment: I think it's just produced as part of the build process, if you wanted to, since the JSON artifact is JSON, you could access it and display in your dapp.

Comment: Do we need those sol files mentioned in absolute path on same location where web3 apis are hosted?

Comment: don't think so, generally speaking in my experience, all you need is the path to the file, and perhaps the contract address if you are deploying to multiple networks (ropsten, kovan and/or mainnet)

Comment: why we need the path of files if we are not uploading files on that location?

Comment: It's included by default, I'm not sure why it's there, but I guess it's useful to have.

Comment: @AmitModi Some tools like Truffle, Remix or Solc will generate JSON artifacts with extra information for debuging purposes. But I do not think it is a closed format and tools can customize for it. What tool are you using that produces such format?

Comment: @Ismael I used truffle compile only.